# how to write multiple lines every time by columns to a file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if the title looks confused to you. I want to create a very big tab-delimited file. Every time I want to write multiple lines (say 3 lines). Since for my case, it is easier to write by columns instead of every line. Specifically, if there are 5 columns(field) for every line, each time I want to write row 1, row 2, row 3 for each column, instead of column 1, column 2, ...column5 for each line. Is there some way to implement this in python3? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Show us what you've attempted so we can see where your code isn't working. If you want help you have to show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could buffer your writes made in a column wise order and make actual writes (prints) in row order:

First, lets write to the buffer in column order:

```
buffer = []    
for col in range(1,3):
    line = []
    for row in range(1,4):
        line.append("r%s-c%s"%(row,col))
    buffer.append(line)
```

If we print it as is, the rows and columns will be reversed:

```
for row in buffer:
    print("\t".join(row))

# r1-c1  r2-c1  r3-c1
# r1-c2  r2-c2  r3-c2
```

But you can use numpy to transpose the buffer before printing:

```
import numpy as np
buffer = np.transpose(buffer)
```

Then printing (or writing to a file) can be done in row order from the adjusted buffer:

```
for row in buffer:
    print("\t".join(row))

# r1-c1  r1-c2
# r2-c1  r2-c2
# r3-c1  r3-c2
```

[EDIT] found something even simpler ...

Without using numpy nor transposing the buffer, you can go through it in inverted order directly using zip():

```
for row in zip(*buffer):
    print("\t".join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Files are read and written line by line, because of the file-structure on your operating system.
For your problem: You can manually buffer your columns and write then line by line. Python itself has no helper for your issue...